# C# byte array into variables

Tags: c#, byte

I have a byte array and I would like to get values from it into variables.
I know the values format like string, unsigned int etc.

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("binarydata.bin");
string value1 = ???
uint16 value2 = ???
string value3 = ???
uint32 value4 = ???
```

How can i assign the values? I know that the first value is a string of 8, i know the second value is a usigned 16bit int, and the third value is a string of 12 and the forth is a unsigned 32 bit int.

Comment: [`BitConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=netframework-4.7) class

Comment: Use `BinaryReader` or `BitConverter`.

Comment: How was this file created? This is important to know, because the `string` value will need some metadata to be present in the file to indicate the length of the string. (Usually length prefixed, but who knows?)

Comment: Using BitConverter and ToString i get the value as hexadecimal instead of human readable text, how can I get it so its readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use [`BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Reads primitive data types as binary values in a specific encoding

**Example**

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
{
    var aspectRatio = reader.ReadSingle();
    var tempDirectory = reader.ReadString();
    var autoSaveTime = reader.ReadInt32();
    var showStatusBar = reader.ReadBoolean();

    Console.WriteLine("Aspect ratio set to: " + aspectRatio);
    Console.WriteLine("Temp directory is: " + tempDirectory);
    Console.WriteLine("Auto save time set to: " + autoSaveTime);
    Console.WriteLine("Show status bar: " + showStatusBar);
}
```

**Update** from xanatos

**ReadString** Reads a string from the current stream. The string is prefixed with the length, encoded as an integer seven bits at a time.

Comment: Put a note on the format the `ReadString()` expects. I don't think anyone else codifies strings in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BinaryReader ,this example writes data as binary. After reads binary data and assigns to variables.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class ConsoleApplication
{
const string fileName = "AppSettings.dat";

static void Main()
{
    WriteDefaultValues();
    DisplayValues();
}

public static void WriteDefaultValues()
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        writer.Write(1.250F);
        writer.Write(@"c:\Temp");
        writer.Write(10);
        writer.Write(true);
    }
}

public static void DisplayValues()
{
    float aspectRatio;
    string tempDirectory;
    int autoSaveTime;
    bool showStatusBar;

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            aspectRatio = reader.ReadSingle();
            tempDirectory = reader.ReadString();
            autoSaveTime = reader.ReadInt32();
            showStatusBar = reader.ReadBoolean();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Aspect ratio set to: " + aspectRatio);
        Console.WriteLine("Temp directory is: " + tempDirectory);
        Console.WriteLine("Auto save time set to: " + autoSaveTime);
        Console.WriteLine("Show status bar: " + showStatusBar);
        }
    }
}
```